# cleanup constructors method

Tags: php, object, constructor, code-cleanup, construct

I have a class with a large number of parameters in the construct method

```
class Foo {
  public $d1;
  public $d2;
  public $d3;
  ...
  public function __construct($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6)
  {
   $this->d1 = $bar->d1;
   $this->d2 = $bar->d2;
   ...  
  }
}
```

I want to clean the code in method __construct

my try :

```
class Bar {
  public $d1;
  public $d2;
  public $d3;
  ...
}

class Foo {
  public $d1;
  public $d2;
  public $d3;
  ...
  public function __construct(Bar $bar)
  {
   $this->d1 = $bar->d1;
   $this->d2 = $bar->d2;
   ...
  }
}
```

In this structure, I want to observe two important points :
1 - clean code
2 - Whenever someone wants to make an object of this class, he must make it according to the structure of the Bar class

Is my structure correct? Do you have a better offer?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? PHP 8 has something called "Constructor Property Promotion" which could make this very clean and concise.

Comment: Also it would be worth looking at extending classes as it will reduce repetition in the `Foo` example class you've given.

Comment: I am using version PHP 7.4